Under or in a carport?
Which preposition is correct? Under or in? I think in is the correct one but I am not sure as there are partly enclosed carports and there are also carports which are canopy-like.
She has a carport she parks her car in/under.

This American has never heard under a carport, but I wouldn’t rule it out, especially if the carport in question is little more than an awning supported by a few legs. Anyway, I don’t think you can go wrong with in.

@PaulTanenbaum Parking your car under a carport will keep the temperature much cooler, making it easier to jump in and go without all the fanning, waiting, and potentially burning your hands on the dash or steering wheel. Farm and Yard (Texas) - I gather it can get hot in Tx.

Is it under or in then?

Why do people downvotes these questions? I don't get it.

Does this answer your question? "In" or "under" the shade of a tree. Also In a gazebo or under a gazebo? and "Under a different light" or "in a different light"

It's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other1...

...where the preposition reflects whether you think of the carport as a roof or a container.

1 OK, so it's eight of one and four of the other. The point is both prepositions are perfectly common, and no-one will care which you use.

You can use either one. If you want to get picky about it, it really depends on what kind of carport it is.
If it's totally exposed and has no walls, it is similar to an awning. It's hard to park in it because there is no inside. It's all outside. But you can park under it. So, just like you would say you sit under an awning, I would say you park under or underneath a carport if it has no walls.
If it has walls and is enclosed, then there is an inside, similar to a garage. In that case, I would say you park in the carport.

As my usage chart shows, in the carport is actually noticeably more common than under the carport. Not that it really matters which is more common, since both are sufficiently common that no-one should notice or care which you use. My downvote is because this answer implies there's a right and a wrong choice of preposition here, and learners have to learn the right one. Which is completely untrue.

@FumbleFingers - it's a fairly common thing on here to find OPs who insist on being given the one true answer, and very often responders who think that they  are doing that.

Truly a nightmare! I think you're right - the kind of learners who ask here are probably more likely than average to think there is only one right answer, and there are always people who don't realise that the version they know isn't used by every other "competent" Anglophone. So the poor learner ends up getting ridiculously confused. I learned my lesson when i realised some people naturally say I could care less instead of I couldn't care less. The former makes no sense whatsoever to me, but people say it. In fact I just heard Elon Musk say it last night (but I accept it now! :)
